# Make empty Div in Flex 100% Height

Tags: html, css

Using the following my `.divider` `<div>` is not showing.  I guess this is because it is empty.  If I add a "." in there, then I see it.  Is it possible to make it `100%` the `height` of the `.wrapper` without adding content?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
}

.left {
  background-color: gray;
}
.divider {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
}
.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sub7fxk5/

Comment: Try adding `min-height: 20px;` to `.wrapper` or add an empty span inside the wrapper div

Comment: Yeah, I read about the empty span somewhere else, but that doesn't seem to work.  Also, whilst my demo has just 1 line of text so 20px would simulate, in reality those left and right divs could be any height and I'm looking to get the divider to extend to full height also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%;` for `.divider`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
}

.left {
  background-color: gray;
}
.divider {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  width: 12px;
  /* height: 100%; */
}
.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boom!  Who'd have thought that what I needed to get it 100% was to remove the style height: 100%??!!

Comment: Yeah, super counter intuitive that height: 100% may make the height 0 and removing it will make height 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `height` and adding `flex: 1` seems to help.
Is the result of the code below what you expect it to be?

The wrapper has no height, that means that setting a `height` to `100%` would equal setting the `height` to `0`.
the `flex: 1` makes the item flexible even though it has no content and it shows.
Of course you can set a width too. So `width: 12px` would work. As would `width: 100%;` (which would push the left and right item to the other side)

You might also use a pseudo-element `::after` as a divider. That would clean up your html a bit.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
}

.left {
  background-color: gray;
}
.divider {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  flex: 1;
}
.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left<br/><br/>Left</div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```